# asyncio: TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon

Try make my code more asynchronous and get this eror:

**find = (await loop.run_until_complete(a.finddb()[0]))**
**TypeError: 'coroutine' object is not subscriptable**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, Button, utils, sync
import pymongo
from pymongo import TEXT
import re
import logging
import asyncio

class Search(): # search in mongodb
    def __init__(self, search): # connect to mongoDB
        self.search = search
        self.myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(
            "mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
        self.mydb = self.myclient["info"]
        self.mycol = self.mydb["comics"]


    async def searchdb(self): # finds all comics by request
        self.mycol.create_index([('title', TEXT)], default_language='english')
        self.find = self.mycol.find({"$text": {"$search": self.search}})
        if self.find.count() == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return (self.find)

    async def finddb(self): # search info for 1 comics
        self.mycol.create_index([('title', TEXT)], default_language='english')
        self.find = self.mycol.find({"title": self.search})
        return (self.find)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'(?<=|).*(?=|)')) # command for find comics info
async def find(event):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    a = Search(event.text.replace("|", ""))
    find = await loop.run_until_complete(a.finddb()[0])
    await event.respond(f'**|{find.get("title")}|**\n\n**Статус перевода**: {find.get("status")}\n**Издатель**: {find.get("publisher")}\n\n**Жанр**: {find.get("genres")}\n**Описание**:\n{find.get("description")}', buttons=[[Button.inline('Ссылки на скачку',  b'next')]])
```

I try to use motor, but have same problem, but why it doesn't work? With pymongo it work perfect

New trouble **find = (await a.finddb())[0] TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not subscriptable**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, Button, utils, sync
import re
import logging
import motor.motor_asyncio

class Search(): # search in mongodb
    def __init__(self, search): # connect to mongoDB
        self.search = search
        self.myclient = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb+srv://login:pass@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")
        self.mydb = self.myclient["info"]
        self.mycol = self.mydb["comics"]



    async def searchdb(self): # finds all comics by request
        self.find = self.mycol.find({"$text": {"$search": self.search}})
        print(self.find)
        if self.find.count() == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return (self.find)

    async def finddb(self): # search info for 1 comics
        self.find = self.mycol.find({"title": self.search})
        return (self.find)

@bot.on(events.NewMessage(pattern=r'(?<=|).*(?=|)')) # command for find comics info
async def find(event):
    a = Search(event.text.replace("|", ""))
    find = (await a.finddb())[0]
    print(find)
    await event.respond(f'**|{find.get("title")}|**\n\n**Статус перевода**: {find.get("status")}\n**Издатель**: {find.get("publisher")}\n\n**Жанр**: {find.get("genres")}\n**Описание**:\n{find.get("description")}', buttons=[[Button.inline('Ссылки на скачку',  b'next')]])
```

Comment: This says that `a.finddb()` returns a `coroutine` object, which isn't something you can treat like a list by asking for its first item.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let's start with some general notes. `find` is defined as a coroutine.

```
async def finddb(self):
```

You need to await it in order to execute it.

```
db = await self.finddb()
```

You can then index into its return value.

```
db[0]
```

If you'd like to continue to do this all in one line, you'll need to wrap it in parentheses.

```
(await self.finddb())[0]
```

Now onto your actual code. `find` is also a coroutine. You can't start an event loop inside one. When you call `loop.run_until_complete`, you're going to get a `RuntimeError` because the loop is already running. You also can't await `run_until_complete` as it isn't a coroutine. (`await` and `run_until_complete` are both ways to run a coroutine or task. The former is used inside a coroutine; the latter is used outside one.)

You can reduce your code to

```
find = (await a.finddb())[0]
```

You can also further simplify it by using PyMongo's `find_one` rather than `find` if you only ever care about the first document it returns.

Lastly, PyMongo itself is not asyncio-aware. You are effectively writing synchronous code with the added overhead of an event loop. If you'd like to potentially benefit from asyncio, you should look at using [Motor](https://github.com/mongodb/motor) instead.

Comment: Thanks you, now I understand my mistake

Comment: Can you please help me again, I change client to  `self.myclient = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient("mongodb+srv://login:pass@cluster0.ye4cx.mongodb.net/info?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE")`
and have error `message = await event.get_message() TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not subscriptable` or `find = (await a.finddb())[0] TypeError: 'AsyncIOMotorCursor' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: As I said above, you should use `find_one` instead of `find`.